# Cotangent complex of a formal thickening

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, deformation-theory, derived-algebraic-geometry, cotangent-complex

Let $R$ be an (animated) commutative ring, with cotangent complex $L_R$ and let $\mathcal{C}(R) = \mathcal{D}(R)_{\Sigma^{-1}L_R/}$ be the category of nice square zero extensions of $R$. A typical object of $\mathcal{C}(R)$ would consist of an $R$-module $I$, a map $L_R \to \Sigma I$. The reason these are called square zero extensions is that $\delta$ classifies a section of the projection $R \oplus \Sigma I \to R$, it's the pullback of this section with the zero section that produces the usual $I \to R' \to R$.

I am interested in deforming an $R$-algebra $A$ to some $R'$-algebra $A'$ such that $A' \otimes_{R'} R \simeq A$. Let me sketch a procedure to locate the desired $A'$ as an element of $\mathcal{C}(A)$. We may note that we nearly have a candidate $\delta \otimes \operatorname{id}_A: L_R \otimes A \to \Sigma I \otimes A$. But we need a map from $L_A$ instead.

Applying $\operatorname{Hom}_A({-}, \Sigma I \otimes A)$ to the transitivity sequence $L_R \otimes A \to L_A \to L_{A/R}$ and rotating, we quickly find an obstruction to extending our map in $\operatorname{Hom}_A(L_{A/R}, \Sigma^2 I \otimes A)$ and that extensions when they exist are a torsor for $\operatorname{Hom}_A(L_{A/R}, \Sigma I \otimes A)$.

Well, forgive the cheap review. I was wondering about what is required to iterate this procedure, whether one could put the next steps in this modern language. So supposing this procedure has succeeded in lifting to $R'$: can one give a nice description of $L_{A'/R'}$ or other modules over $A'$ in terms of this data?

More particularly, suppose I have some decent control of $L_A$, $L_{A/R}$, $L_{A/A'}$, $L_{R/R'}$, as I believe I do by an inductive hypothesis. Can I get an explicit handle on $L_{A'/R'}?$ Manipulation of transitivity sequences has given me nothing so far.

Comment: One useful property is $L_{A'/R'}\otimes_{R'} R\cong L_{A/R}$. This implies, for example, that the perfect amplitudes of $L_{A/R}$ and $L_{A'/R'}$ agree (and often this is what one cares about). I'm not aware of any concrete formula for $L_{A'/R'}$, however.